# DataTables in c#

Tags: c#

I am importing an excel sheet to a DataTable in a window application using oledb and want to fetch only the date which is the first column in my excel sheet. I have entered only dates in this column. but DataTable is adding time to it which I don't want.
How to get only date in the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `Date` data type in .NET. All date values come out as `DateTime`. You can get the date with a "0" time value using `datevalue.Date`.

Comment: thanks for that one.
but now I'm getting following exception.

Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {00020820-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 80010001.

I am referencing 
Microsoft office 11.0 object library
Microsoft Excel 11.0 object library

and using as

using Core = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

please help

Comment: Well, that would be stuff for a separate question, as it has nothing to do with converting the date values. When asking this question, please make sure you post some code.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting Thorsten:

> There is no Date data type in .NET. All date values come out as DateTime. You can get the date with a "0" time value using datevalue.Date.

Also be careful: if you inserted dates with "0 time" and you're getting back dates with non-zero time maybe you're running into one of those Excel date-format issues (thus your date should be quite different from the one you've input).

Answer (score 0):

**Use Linq on DataTable**

```
 string[] array = gdt01T01S060
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Select(row => row.Field<string>("RequestedPartNo"))
              .ToArray();


for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            array[i] = Convert.ToDateTime(array[i]).ToString("mm/dd/yyyy");
        }
```

check out the date format. according to you.